# PHP fgetc read á or ě

Tags: php

Can you help me?
I write command line script in php. I need to read char from file , which i open by `fopen`. I use `fgetc`, but letter like `á, ž, é, ř` etc. are incorrect.

```
$this->inputFile=fopen(arguments::$input, "r");
$char=fgetc($this->inputFile);
echo "char: ".$char."\n";
```

output of `á or ř` is `�`

Comment: It'd more than likely be an encoding issue (*UTF8*)

Comment: Input file is in UTF8. If I read file by line (fgets) output of line is ok.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3800330/2518525) might be worth reading too